# Kill hair particles that go over plane

Tags: particles

I am using a hair particle system to scatter grass around. However, the models being used for the grass are already bunches of grass themselves, meaning they are considerably wider than the "original hairs" and which causes them to go over the edge of the plane where I'm using them.

My question is rather obvious: is there a way to mask or kill generated geometry that goes over the boundaries of the emitter, or when it collides with other geometry (like the grey border in my image)?

Thanks!

[image: Clipping]